# awk Group By & "Reduce"

Tags: awk, json, jq

Let's say I have data like the following:

```
table_name id
table_name col_1
table_name col_2
another_table_name id
another_table_name col_1
```

How can I use `awk` to group by the first column and reduce the second to a comma-separated list? Per the example, the output should be:

```
table_name id,col_1,col_2
another_table_name id,col_1
```

The idea here is I can use the second column to construct a JSON array (the value) via `jq` based on the data in first column (the key):

```json
{"table_name": ["id", "col_1", "col_2"]}
{"another_table_name": ["id", "col_1"]}
```

Have everything working except the grouby / "reduce" step; any help is most appreciated!

Comment: If the file isn't big: `awk '{a[$1]=a[$1]","$2}END{for(i in a)print i a[i]}' file`

Comment: Or (in order to obtain the (idiosyncratic) required format `awk '{a[$1]=a[$1]","$2}END{for(i in a)print i,substr(a[i],2)}' file`: But the "correctly escaping json strings" part is much more interesting than you think.

Comment: @user414777, just to check my understanding -- your solution chains columns two entries together (in the first set of braces) and then prints each key followed by this chain in the second set of braces, right?

Comment: Yes. Just as you would've done to build that in javascript. This does not assume that the lines are sorted. But as everything's stored in memory, this will not work with *very* large files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest option to create your JSON structure would be by using [the `jo` utility](https://jpmens.net/2016/03/05/a-shell-command-to-create-json-jo/):

```
$ sed 's/[[:blank:]]\{1,\}/[]=/' file | jo -p
{
   "table_name": [
      "id",
      "col_1",
      "col_2"
   ],
   "another_table_name": [
      "id",
      "col_1"
   ]
}
```

The `sed` script creates the input for `jo` by replacing the first run of spaces or tabs by `[]=`. With your example data this yields

```
table_name[]=id
table_name[]=col_1
table_name[]=col_2
another_table_name[]=id
another_table_name[]=col_1
```

The `jo` utility then takes care of properly encoding the data and creating the JSON document.  Drop the `-p` option to `jo` if you want compact output.

---

Old answer using `jq` instead, but does not take care of data that needs JSON encoding:

Assuming none of the data needs special JSON encoding:

```
jq -n "$(awk '{ printf ".\"%s\" += [\"%s\"] |\n", $1, $2 } END { print "." }' file)"
```

or

```
awk '{ printf ".\"%s\" += [\"%s\"] |\n", $1, $2 } END { print "." }' file |
jq -n -f /dev/stdin
```

This uses `awk` to create `jq` expressions that builds your arrays.  For the given example data, the `jq` expression would be

```
."table_name" += ["id"] |
."table_name" += ["col_1"] |
."table_name" += ["col_2"] |
."another_table_name" += ["id"] |
."another_table_name" += ["col_1"] |
.
```

When evaluated by `jq`, this creates the JSON document

```json
{
  "table_name": [
    "id",
    "col_1",
    "col_2"
  ],
  "another_table_name": [
    "id",
    "col_1"
  ]
}
```

Add the `-c` option to `jq` to get compact output.

---

Using `sed` instead of `awk`:

```
sed -e 's/\([^[:blank:]]*\)[[:blank:]]*\(.*\)/."\1" += ["\2"] |/' \
    -e '$ s/$/./' file |
jq -n -f /dev/stdin
```

Comment: This is a spectacular answer -- thank you for bringing `jo` to my attention. I was asking about an `awk` solution for my own practice, but I agree with you: it's best take advantage of [much smarter] abstraction if & where I can. :)

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is to remember the first field from the previous line, and if it is the same then print out a comma and the second field otherwise print the first and second fields. Then handle some boundary cases

```
awk '$1 == saved { printf(",%s", $2); next ; }
     neednl { print ""; }
     { saved=$1 ; neednl=1 ;printf("%s %s",$1,$2) ; }
     END { if (neednl) { print "" ; }}'
```